# How to take the text form a file within <> (regex)

Tags: bash, files, text

How can i take the text from a file that is between < > and the one that is not:
file:

```
hello<world>
```

within <>: world

without <>: hello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough. What should happen when there are more than one character of `<` or `>` on the *same* line?

Assuming that there is only one tag within `<>` on a line in the file, the following should do your job:

```
$ sed 's/<.*>//' your_file
```

The above will delete *all* the stings in the file that start with `<` and end with `>` and will print the remaining.

```
$ sed 's/^.*<//; s/>.*$//' your_file
```

The above will delete all the strings up to *last* `<` in the line. And after that, it will delete all the strings starting with the *first* `>` in the line. For example:

```
$ echo '111<aaa>222<bbb>333<ccc>444' | sed 's/^.*<//; s/>.*$//'
ccc
```

If you want to find the *first* "tag", then try this:

```
$ echo '111<aaa>222<bbb>333<ccc>444' | sed 's/^[^<]*<//; s/>.*$//'
aaa
```

If you want to print the string between the *first* `<` and the *last* `>`, try this:

```
$ echo '111<aaa>222<bbb>333<ccc>444' | sed 's/^[^<]*<//; s/>[^>]*$//'
aaa>222<bbb>333<ccc
```